# Active graphics card: unknown - no HDMI connection

Tags: nvidia, intel, hdmi

I have seen similar threads around here but they do not exactly answer my question.

Towards the end of last year, my HDMI connection (external screen) did not work anymore on my Linux Mint partition (it does work on my Windows 10 partition - I'm working on dual boot). This remained the case in spite of several updates including NVIDIA drivers (through the update manager). The NVIDIA X Server settings icon remains red and states "Active graphics card: unknown". When I open it up, I get the choice between "NVIDIA (Performance Mode)" and "Intel (Power Saving Mode"). When I choose NVIDIA, it asks me to restart in order to apply the new changes, however, it always reverts back to Intel.

It does seem that my system recognises my GPU (also confirmed with `inxi -Fxz`).

I just had a kernel upgrade as well as an update to the drivers (384). For both upgrades, I noticed something about around two firmware files being missing (I think at least one or both of them was a .bin), and there being no support for my locale (en_ZA.UTF-8). I don't know how to retrieve the installation log files.

Four other things perhaps worth mentioning:

- I don't remember making any big updates or changes to system settings before it started to happen.
- My GRUB menu disappeared some time ago. I have to press F9 to make it appear, otherwise Windows boots by default.
- Very often, shutting down my computer while on Mint leads to a very protracted shutting down process (perhaps ten minutes or so). A screen quickly flashes reporting something about a bus error being corrected.
- Very often, I am not able to mount my Windows drives (C: and D:). I am not able to duplicate the problem right now and I can't remember the error message. If I restart, the problem mostly disappears. It could be that the last kernel upgrade or two have fixed this. I mostly work on another laptop at work and only occasionally on this partition at home.

I'm hesitant to purge anything as the last time I did this (on Ubuntu) I was not able to log in (blank screen).

My graphics info:

- Card-1: Intel HD Graphics 630 bus-ID: 00:02.0
- Card-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] bus-ID: 01:00.0
- Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.01hz
- GLX Redenderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2)
- GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5 Direct Rendering: Yes

System info:

- Kernel: 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
- Desktop: Cinnamon 3.6.7 (Gtk 3.18.9-lubuntu3.3)
- Distro: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia

I am using an [HP Omen 15](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CZCFHC6).

EDIT: Added some suspicious lines from `dmesg` output (there are over 1000 lines in total) according to dirkt's suggestion.

EDIT2: Paradox has suggested that I use `lsmod | egrep -i "nouveau|nvidia"`. I have done so but there is no output.

Appreciating your time and effort.

`dmesg` output:

```
[ +0.000003] pci 0000:01:00.0: can't claim BAR 6 [mem 0xfff80000-0xffffffff pref]: no compatible bridge window
[ +0.003345] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[ +0.001709] (NULL device *): hwmon_device_register() is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use hwmon_device_register_with_info().
[ +0.000411] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[ +0.003274] usbhid 1-1:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[ +0.000002] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[ +0.000001] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
[ +0.000119] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:01: WQBC data block query control method not found
[ +0.000016] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:01: WQBJ data block query control method not found
[ +0.150028] (NULL device *): hwmon_device_register() is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use hwmon_device_register_with_info().
[ +0.036953] hp_accel: laptop model unknown, using default axes configuration
[ +0.000488] (NULL device *): hwmon_device_register() is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use hwmon_device_register_with_info().
[ +0.000011] thermal thermal_zone4: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[ +0.237212] hp_wmi: query 0xd returned error 0x5
[ +0.009258] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Wide Vision HD (05c8:038e)
[ +0.004332] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[ +0.000001] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[ +0.000001] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[ +0.525991] new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
```

Comment: Guess: Some other driver (nouveau?) is claiming the Nvidia card, so the Nvidia kernel driver doesn't get loaded, so the Nvidia X driver can't see the card. Verify by looking at `dmesg` after boot, look which drivers get loaded. `lsmod` may also help. I am not familiar with Mint, but if this is the reason, try removing all packages with alternative drivers (nouveau etc.), and reinstall the proprietary NVIDIA drivers. Also, the last time I looked installing both Intel and Nvidia GLX libraries wasn't easy (but that wasn't on Mint).

Comment: Please, could you edit the question with the output of commands instead of putting it in comments? You should try `lsmod | egrep -i "nouveau|nvidia"`.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question and will add output once I have access to my laptop again.

Comment: Paradox, I have now done so but there is no output. Which lines should I be looking at? For example the last one says `video                  45056  1 i915`. Thank you kindly.